# Need collision and trigger on same prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a trigger on each prefab when the player hits a certain key while close to the object. I also need collision between each instance of the prefab and player. I can only seem to get one to work when "is trigger" is selected on the prefab. What's the correct way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a trigger on the objects, use `Physics.OverlapSphere` to find all objects in range **when the player presses the key** and then execute a function in the script on the objects.

**Trigger Event:**

```c#
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        ApplyEffect(transform.position, RADIUS);
    }
}
```

*`RADIUS` is the desired proximity to the player*

**Method 1:**

```c#
void ApplyEffect(Vector3 center, float radius)
{
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hitColliders.Length)
    {
        hitColliders[i].gameObject.GetComponent<SCRIPT_NAME>().EFFECT_FUNCTION();
        i++;
    }
}
```

*`SCRIPT_NAME` is the name of the script on the target objects.* 
*`EFFECT_FUNCTION` is the name of the function in the script.*

**Method 2:** 
Use a messaging system to execute functionality on the objects similar to the function shown in the documentation example:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interface on the objects for when the player is close and hits a certain key. Collision can be handled by the objects collider, is there a specific reason it needs to be a trigger? Check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) out, may clear up some isTrigger issues.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.